# Implementing a Harmonic Product Spectrum algorithm in java

Tags: java, fft, spectrum

I am currently working on a guitar tuner program in Java and
I am trying to implement a Harmonic Product Spectrum Algorithm in order to determine the fundamental frequency.

For the moment, I made a method that downsamples my spectrum by a factor *f*.

I am now trying to multiply all my different downsampled spectrums together.
I am coding in java and working with arrays. 
Consequently I have arrays for the indexes that have been downsampled and arrays for the different values of my spectrum.
I am right now trying to put all of the different arrays to the same size and organize their values so that they correspond to the right downsampled index.
I am having a lot of problems with the size and the values....

Moreover, I am trying to implement this algorithm based on an example I have on sheet of paper... Consequently I can only implement this algorithm with 4 downsampled spectrums, but  I doubt this will be enough when I will actually use a real sound signal.

Here is the code for the downsample method:

```
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

public class SousEchantillonnage {

public static double[] valuesDownSample(double[] tab, int factor){

    int N = tab.length;

    double[] values = new double[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        values[i] = tab[i];
    }

    int lengthDownSample = N + (facteur - 1) * (N - 1);

    double[] valuesDownSample = new double[lengthDownSample];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        valuesDownSample[i] = values[i];
    }
    for (int i = N; i < lengthDownSample; i ++){
        valuesDownSample[i] = 0;
    }

    return valuesDownSample;
}

public static double[] indexDownSample(double[] tab, int factor){

    int N = tab.length;

    double[] indexes = new double[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        indexes[i] = i;
    }

    int lengthDownSample = N + (factor - 1) * (N - 1);

    double[] indexDownSample = new double [lengthDownSample];
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthDownSample; i++){
        indexDownSample[i] = i / factor;
    }

    return indexDownSample;
}
```

This method seems to be working.

Here is my method for the HPS algorithm so far:

```
public static double[] hps(double[] tab){

    int N = tab.length;

    int factor2 = 2;
    int factor3 = 3;
    int factor4 = 4;
    int lengthDownSample2 = N/2 + (factor2 - 1) * (N/2 - 1);
    int lengthDownSample3 = N/2 + (factor3 - 1) * (N/2 - 1);
    int lengthDownSample4 = N/2 + (factor4 - 1) * (N/2 - 1);

            // Gives us the spectrogram of the signal tab
    double[] spectrogram = new double[N];                       
    spectrogramme = FFT.calculFFT(tab);

            // We only need the first values of the spectrogram. The other half is the same.
    double[] spectrogramCut = new double[N/2];          
    for (int i = 0; i < N/2; i++){
        spectrogramCut[i] = spectrogram[i];
    }

            // We create the array that contains the values of spectrogramCut that we downsample by a factor 2
       double[] valuesSpect2 = new double [sizeDownSamp2];  
       valuesSpect2 = SousEchantillonnage.valuesDownSample(spectrogramCut, factor2);

          // We create an array of the indexes of spectrogramCut that we downsample by a factor 2
      double[] indexSpect2 = new double[sizeDownSamp2];
      indexSpect2 = SousEchantillonnage.indexDownSample(spectrogramCut, factor2);

         // We create the array that contains the values of spectrogramCut that we downsample by a factor 3
       double[] valuesSpect3 = new double [sizeDownSamp3];  
       valuesSpect3 = SousEchantillonnage.valuesDownSample(spectrogramCut, factor3);

         // We create an array of the indexes of spectrogramCut that we downsample by a factor 3
    double[] indexSpect3 = new double[sizeDownSamp3];
    indexSpect3 = SousEchantillonnage.indexDownSample(spectrogramCut, factor3);;

       // We create the array that contains the values of spectrogramCut that we            downsample by a factor 4
   double[] valuesSpect4 = new double [sizeDownSamp4];  
   valuesSpect4 = SousEchantillonnage.valuesDownSample(spectrogramCut, factor4);

       // We create an array of the indexes of spectrogramCut that we downsample by a factor 4
    double[] indexSpect4 = new double[sizeDownSamp4];
    indexSpect4 = SousEchantillonnage.indexDownSample(spectrogramCut, factor4);

        int sizeIndex = N/2 + 5 * (N/2 - 1); // size of the array that contains all the       indexes of the downsamples

        // We create this array
    double[] indexDowSamp = new double[sizeIndex];
    indexDowSamp[0] = 0;
    indexDowSamp[1] = 0.25;
    indexDowSamp[2] = 0.333;
    indexDowSamp[3] = 0.5;
    indexDowSamp[4] = 0.666;
    indexDowSamp[5] = 0.75;

    int q = sizeIndex / 6;      // quantity of packets of 6 we can do
    int r = sizeIndex%6;        // what we are left with.

    for (int i = 6; i < q * 6; i += 6){
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
        indexDowSamp[i + j] = indexDowSamp[i + j - 6] + 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
        indexDowSamp[q * 6 + i] = indexDowSamp[q * 6 + i - 6] + 1;
    }
```

I am stuck here. I would like to do a method that multiplies two arrays of different length together.

Basically, as you can see, when I downsample a spectrogram, I get two arrays:

- one that has the indexes that were downsamples
- the other that has the values after the downsample.

What I would like to do is create an array that is the same size that `indexDownSample`: `valuesDownSample`.
For instance, we have `indexDownSample[0] = 0`. 
I would like to have for `valuesDownSample[0]` the product of `valuesSpectCut[0] *valuesSpect2[0]*valuesSpect3[0]*valuesSpect4[0]` because all of these arrays have a value that correspond to the index 0 (`indexSpectCut[0] = 0`, `indexSpect2[0] = 0 = indexSpect3[0] = indexSpect4[0]`).

for `indexDownSample[1]=0.25`, we notice that only `indexSpect4[1]= indexDownSample[1] = 0.25`
We are then going to have by default 0 for `valuesDownSample[1]`.

And we continue like this until we filled the array.

If everything goes smoothely, we should have at the end:

- valuesDownSample that contains the different values of the products
- indexDownSample that contains the different downsampled index.

I will just need to find the max peak in order to find my fundamental frequency.

My only problem is that I have no idea how to do the multiplying.....

If someone has an idea, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: It would help a lot if you described what you were actually having problems with and showed at least some of what you've done so far. As it is, right now we have to guess what to suggest…

Comment: why java?!? try c++, fortran, something else!

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.
My project has to be in java. It's not a choice... It was imposed.

Whereas for the code so far here is what I did for the downsampling. I am sorry though my annotations will be in french.....

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I have an actual answer, this is how I solved the issue:

First of all I don't call it downsampling but dividing the frequencies of the FFT. For this I only use 2 arrays like so:

```
float findex[1000]; //index of frequencies for harmonic product spectrum
float mindex[1000]; //index of magnitudes for harmonic product spectrum
unsigned int max_findex;    //number of elements in findex[] and mindex[]
```

This is my initialization:
    max_findex = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        mindex[i] = 0.0;
    }

I'm developing on the Analog Devices Sharc EZ Development Board in VisualDSP++ so my code is in C.

I use a large FFT size of 131072 at a low sampling rate of 12kHz. This gives me a relatively high accuracy of 0.09Hz per bin. Since higher harmonics will be more accurate I start with my highest division first:

```
//first run with max division (highest accuracy)
for (i = 0; i < new_peak; i++) {
    findex[max_findex] = f(peak[i].index) / 9;
    mindex[max_findex] = peak[i].magnitude;
    if (max_findex < 999) max_findex++;
    else xmitUARTmessage("ERROR max_findex\r\n", 100);
}
```

I have all my peaks from the FFT in a struct like so:
peak[].index is the bin number in the FFT, and peak[].magnitude is the magnitude of the peak. The f() function returns the frequency of a bin.

Next I would go to division 8, then 7, etc. and division 1 (actual frequencies comes last).
For each peak that is divided I look through my array to see if I already have a frequency at this point. I use +/- 0.2 and I could probably tighten that up but you have to adjust it to the accuracy of your FFT.

```
char found;

for (u2 = 8; u2 > 0; u2--) {
    for (i = 0; i < new_peak; i++) {
        tempf = f(peak[i].index) / u2;
        found = 0;
        for (u = 0; u < max_findex; u++) {
            //try to find existing frequency
            if (tempf < findex[u] + 0.2 && tempf > findex[u] - 0.2) {
                //found existing frequency
                mindex[u] *= peak[i].magnitude;
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        } //for u
        if (!found) {
            //no frequency was found, add new one
            findex[max_findex] = tempf;
            mindex[max_findex] = peak[i].magnitude;
            if (max_findex < 999) max_findex++;
            else xmitUARTmessage("ERROR max_findex\r\n", 100);
        }
    } //for i
} //for u2
```

And that's it. Now I just print out my values and sort them by magnitude in Excel...

```
for (i = 0; i < max_findex; i++) {
    sprintf(tempstr, "%.2f,%.2f\r\n", findex[i], mindex[i]);
    xmitUARTmessage(tempstr, 100);
}
```

Here is some output (I only show the top 6):
60.53   1705693250000
60  1558419875000
20  555159950
179.99  264981525
7.5 1317353
8.57    1317353

The input audio signal that created the output was:
60 Hz square wave (fundamental plus odd harmonics)
181.5 Hz sine wave
302.5 Hz sine wave
423.5 Hz sine wave

I was simulating a beat frequency of 60 + 60.5 Hz with the fundamental completely missing at 60.5. This is a tough case and it worked :)